# Diferencia en funciones

Tags: javascript, funciones, function

Que diferencia hay entre

```
miFuncionMostrar = function(){
     código...
};

function miFuncionMostrar (){
     código...
}
```

Porque me no se si sea lo mismo o dependendiendo de como vaya es lo que va hacer mi función?

---

```
mostrarHtml = function()
 {
    var html = "";
          html += '<table class="table table-primary" id="info" style="margin-top: 20px">';
          html += '<thead> <tr> <th> Ejemplo de tabla </th> </tr></thead>';
          html += '</tbody></table>;
 };
```

En el ejemplo lo puse así muy simple sin completarlo para que no sea todo el código de mi html pero es algo así

Comment: Así como esta el primero parece un error de sintaxis, seguro que no era esto lo que querías comparar `let miFuncion = function() {...............}`

Comment: El primero para llamar la función en html porque si lo acepta poniendolo en input, botones seguido de los paréntesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay diferencias.. Consideremos:

```js
console.log(sumar(1,2)) // 3

console.log(miSuma) // la variable fue definida pero es undefined

/* 
  Si en cambio le pasamos argumentos, la misma no funciona.
  Descomentar la linea de abajo para visualizar el error
*/

// console.log(miSuma(3,2)) // Error

function sumar(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

var miSuma = function (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log(miSuma(3,2)) // 5
```

La primera es lo que se conoce como una declaración de función y la segunda es una expresión de función, asignada a una variable específica.

La diferencia es que las declaraciones son procesadas y evaluadas antes que las expresiones de función en lo que se conoce etapa de "creación" realizada por intérprete JavaScript.

Esto quiere decir que las declaraciones de funciones siempre van a estar disponibles en cualquier lugar y momento del código. En cambio, las expresiones de función (que están asignadas a variables) tienen que esperar a ser asignadas un valor. Esto ocurre después en la etapa que se conoce como "ejecución".

**Importante**: Todas las variables se definen en la etapa de "creación" (controlada por el intérprete JavaScript) y se les asigna un valor `undefined` por defecto. Este proceso se llama "hoisting" (traducido al español sería algo así como "elevación").

Mas información [acá](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones#constructor_versus_declaration_versus_expression)

Answer (score 1):

**Opción 1**

Cuando le asignas a una variable la igualdad con una función anónima como en el siguiente caso (y la has declarado con **`let`** o **`const`**):

```
let operacionUno = function () {
  console.log(1)
}
```

Tendrás las siguientes características:

- Solo puede ser invocada después de haber sido creada
- Se accede por medio del nombre de la variable
- No puedes invocarla antes de donde es declarada o te va a dar un error de este tipo

> "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'operacionUno' before initialization

- El error cambia si la declaras con **`var`** pues en caso de ser así: el mensaje será:

> "TypeError: operacionUno is not a function

**Opción 2**

Si por el contrario declaras una función a la cual le asignas un nombre que es por medio del cual la invocarás, del modo siguiente:

```
operacionUno()
function operacionUno() {
  console.log(1)
}

operacionUno()
```

Entonces te dará como salida:

> 11

Es decir puedes invocar a la función aún antes de ser declarada.

Aquí [puedes consultar mas al respecto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)